# How many symphonic instruments in the same group to specify

Tags: notation, orchestra

In a symphonic orchestra, or any other, how many of the same instruments do I specify in the score, if they play the same score?

For example, for violins, there is just one line.  What about the woodwinds or brass instruments?

Comment: Hi @EugeniyaBentsman - welcome. If you have an answer that is valuable, please select the check mark next to it to indicate you accept that answer. That helps future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Violins are traditionally divided into two sections, so there will normally be two lines.  In addition, the violas, cellos, and basses are one section each, though sometimes the basses and cellos are written as one section and sometimes as two.  Exceptions are fairly frequent.  The number of players in each section is usually not specified; it is left to the conductor's discretion.

Other instruments are typically written for a single player on each part (though multiple parts are typically written on a single staff un the score).  There are examples of performances where winds and/or brass were "doubled" in the sense of having multiple players for each part, but this is not the standard practice (in an orchestra; bands are another matter entirely).  So for example a standard classical-era woodwind section will be written on four staves in tbe score, one each for flute, oboe, clarinet, and bassoon, with two parts on each staff, played by one player each, for a total of eight woodwind players in tbe orchestra.  As orchestras expanded in tbe 19th century the number of staves increased.